# How can I check if the date already exists using code Behind?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a date just one "DateOfyear" and I want to check before inserting the date in the textbox is already exists in DB but using code behind in C#.

I will give a example like what I want to do, I know is not the right code or what I need, but is just a example because I don't want peoples to past or give solution with SQLCommand/SqlServer and other thing I want something like that code.

```
DateTime InvoiceDateFrom = new DateTime();
DateTime InvoiceDateTo = new DateTime();
InvoiceDateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDatRiferiment.Text);
InvoiceDateTo = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDatRiferiment.Text);
if (InvoiceDateFrom == InvoiceDateTo)
{
    errorMessage = vea.ErrorMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DateTime.compareTo method:

```
if(InvoiceDateFrom.CompareTo(InvoiceDateTo) == 0){
    errorMessage = vea.ErrorMessage;
}
```

More info [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.compareto?view=netframework-4.8)